# What parameters should i set to process a 100 GB Csv in Spark 1.6

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark, my usecase is to process a 100 Gb file in spark and load it in hive. I have a 2 node 128GB ram each cluster. By processing I mean to add an extra column to my existing csv, whose value is calculated at run time.
 But everytime I run spark-submit it fails throwing the below error:-

```
Exception in thread "task-result-getter-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.read(UTF8String.java:1205)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$KryoSerializableSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:363)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$KryoSerializableSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:355)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:729)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.read(DefaultArraySerializers.java:338)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.read(DefaultArraySerializers.java:293)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:648)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.read(FieldSerializer.java:605)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:221)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:729)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.read(DefaultArraySerializers.java:338)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.read(DefaultArraySerializers.java:293)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:729)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.deserialize(KryoSerializer.scala:311)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DirectTaskResult.value(TaskResult.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(TaskResultGetter.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1819)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2.run(TaskResultGetter.scala:50)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The command i am trying to use is below:-

```
spark-submit --master yarn-client \
             --executor-memory 8G --total-executor-cores 2 \
             --class "com.test.app.Test" \
             spark.old-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
             harshaltestdata   harshaltestdata  \
             --jars spark-csv_2.10-1.5.0.jar
```

Note:

- `harshaltestdata`   is my Csv name which is in HDFS
- `harshaltestdata`    is my table name.

I have tried the code for file upto 50 mb and its working fine , but when i try it with more than  100 Mb it fails.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    //table csv name as in
    val csvName = args(0)
    val tableName = args(1)
    System.setProperty("SPARK_YARN_MODE", "true");
    val sparkConfiguration = new SparkConf();
    sparkConfiguration.setMaster("yarn-client");
    sparkConfiguration.setAppName("test-spark-job");
    sparkConfiguration
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "12g")
      .set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "512")

    val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConfiguration);
    println("started spark job")
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sparkContext)
    val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sparkContext)

    val data = hiveContext.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
      .load("hdfs_path***" + csvName + ".csv");
    //Printing in lines
    data.collect().foreach(println)
    //Printing in tabular form
    data.show()
    val newdf = data.withColumn("date", lit("10-04-19"))
    newdf.withColumn("date", lit("10-04-19"))
    newdf.write.mode("append").saveAsTable(tableName)

    val d = hiveContext.sql("select * from " + tableName)
    d.show()
    }
    }
```

Expected results are that the file should get processed and be loaded in Hive

Comment: To optimize and understand spark and memory , please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43460631/7796098

Answer (score 1):

Never use `collect()` if you don't really need it, it will cause Memory issue especially when you have big CSV file.

And the second line is redundant, you can remove it.

```
val newdf = data.withColumn("date", lit("10-04-19"))
newdf.withColumn("date", lit("10-04-19")) // It means nothing, you can remove it.
newdf.write.mode("append").saveAsTable(tableName)
```